# Android App Crashes When Thread Is Interupted

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-thread

I have a thread running in my app but when it finishes its workand i try and stop it the thread crashes the app and restarts leading to a loop of crashes till i reopen the app
The Runnable:

```
final class TheThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        if (!thread.isInterrupted()){
        //dowork
        thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

The Thread Creation:(The variable thread is intallized in the oncreate methoed as a regular Thread object)

```
    thread = new Thread(new TheThread());
    thread.setPriority(START_STICKY);
    thread.start();
```

Comment: you are not implementing the Runnable so this code shouldn't even compile!

Comment: Whats the Crash about add the crash report . And what is `thread.setPriority(START_STICKY);`? priority ranges between 1-10..

Comment: i am implementing runnable i forgot to write it in the code (sorry i edited it now) and ill get the crash report now and the start sticky is for it to run in the background even when app is closed(START_STICKY is int i just dont know the number check it in android studio)

Comment: What your crash is saying? Share crash information

Comment: START_STICKY is not for threads it's for service.you are using it wrong

Comment: humazed i made it work and not crash with START_STICKY im pretty sure its ment for every long running background process i called looper.prepare() and it stopped crashing and worked flawlessly

Comment: `START_STICKY` is just a integer constant. Where as its a int you should not use it anywhere else other than `Service` the code will get totally confusing.

Comment: inside said thread there is  a service running and well for now it works sooo im prety sure youre right i just got lucky so thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Found The Problom I Needed To Call Looper.Preper();